# Recursos de Google Drive

Tags: php, jquery, servidor, google-drive

Tengo un archivo llamado `prueba.js` en mi `Drive`, el cual quiero utilizar en mi `aplicación WEB` que se encuentra alojada en otro servidor, este archivo tiene una `función` llamada verificar la cual quiero que se ejecute en mi WEB, deje el archivo en modo `cualquiera en la web puede encontrar/ver` despues en mi proyecto

```
<script src="https://ruta" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

pero no encuentra la función, el archivo lo muestra vació
mi pregunta es.
¿Puedo hacer utilizar ese archivo que esta en el `drive` en mi aplicación sin necesidad de agregarlo en el proyecto, si es así como podría hacerlo?.

Nota: mi proyecto esta echo en `PHP`

Comment: Entiendo que no puedes hacerlo. Ahora por que razon tendrias un archivo de tu proyecto en gdrive? que sentido tiene?

Comment: Quiero obtener un código que se encuentra en ese archivo, y no quiero que se encuentre en el mismo  servidor, y lo pues en drive

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive tenía la función de alojar sitios web pero dicha función fue retirada hace tiempo (me parece que ya son varios años), sin embargo hay un truco para descargar un archivo mediante un URL

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ID_DE_TU_ARCHIVO
```

Nota: Puedes cambiar "download" por "view" para mostrar el archivo en el navegador

Me parece que lo podrás usar pero deberás tomar la decisión de si vas a obtener el código del lado del servidor o del lado del cliente.